# Accessing the DOM in a Firefox for Android add-on

Tags: android, firefox-addon

This sounds like a very simple question, but I've been going through the MDN documentation of "Firefox for Android" and I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to build a simple "Firefox for Android" add-on, which simply inserts a script tag into visited pages. I've tried the following code  (leaving out the [template boilerplate code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/Initialization_and_Cleanup#template_code)):

```
function loadIntoWindow(window) {
  if (!window)
    return;

  menuId = window.NativeWindow.menu.add("Insert", null, function() {
        insertScript(window);
    });
}

function insertScript(window) { 
    // none of these properties exist: window.document.body.innerHTML, window.body.innerHTML
    // window.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>this page has been eaten</h1>";

    // var contentScriptString = 'document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>this page has been eaten</h1>";'

    // throws error "ReferenceError: require is not defined"
    // var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

    // tabs.activeTab.attach({
    //  contentScript: contentScriptString
    // });

    // throws error "TypeError: attach is not a function"
    // window.BrowserApp.selectedTab.attach({
        // contentScript: contentScriptString
    // });
}

function unloadFromWindow(window) {
  if (!window)
    return;

    window.NativeWindow.menu.remove(menuId);
}
```

The loadIntoWindow function is being correctly called, since the "Insert" option is added as a menu option, and this option in turn correctly calls the insertScript option when tapped.

However, I'm at a loss on how to access the window's DOM in order to insert the script. I've tried options mentioned on the page about [content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts) and the [BrowserApp property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/Code_snippets#Looking_up_Tabs_and_Browsers)..

Thanks,

William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I can answer my own question. After looking through [browser.js](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/chrome/content/browser.js), I found that the following code works to access the current page's DOM:

```
var contentWindow = window.BrowserApp.selectedBrowser.contentWindow;
var document = contentWindow.document;

document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>this page has been eaten</h1>";
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing! I'm getting into android addons now too would you be able to chat some time? Im trying to do simple stuff like find a way to keep the navigation bar staying all the time.

Comment: Regrettably, I only made this one addon & I don't have any other experiences  .. If you like, I can share the code with you.

Comment: Yes please @Will that would be awesome, can you upload to a github repository please? Is your method e10s (electrolysis) safe?